# Parse cloud code with swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am really new to iOS development and I am having trouble with the cloud code aspect of Parse in iOS. I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with this and I know there is similar posts. I have looked at them but nothing stands out and I have tried everything. It is meant to create buttons based on objects in an array produced from cloud code.

Parameters were required in the code but I don't need parameters for my cloud code. So I just send an empty dictionary. I get the error:

> "'AnyObject' is not convertible to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'; did you
>   mean to us 'as!' to force downcast?"

Changing the parameters results in error:

> "Cannot convert value of type '([AnyObject]?, NSError?) -> Void' to
>   expected argument type 'PFIdResultBlock?'"

```
if(currentUser != nil)
{
     let params = NSMutableDictionary()
     params.setObject("", forKey: "")

     PFCloud.callFunctionInBackround("getUserSubjects", withParameters: params as AnyObject, block:
     {
       (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?)  -> Void in
           if(results.count != 0)
           {
              if let results = results
              {
                 for object in results
                 {
                     self.subjectarray.append(object.objectForKey("subject") as! AnyObject)
                 }
              }
              else
              {

              }
              self.createbuttons()
           }
    })
}
```

Comment: `withParameters` is `nullable` so you can just pass `nil` But if you did want to pass an empty dictionary you don't need to downcast it using `as` at all

Comment: Hi Paulw11 thanks, but I have tried this and it gives me the second error about expected argument type 'PFIdResultBlock?'.

Comment: `results:[AnyObject]?` should be `results:AnyObject` (or possibly `AnyObject?`) you can then downcast it to an array

Comment: Thanks Paulw11, that worked a treat :)